# Can Ackermann theory minus foundation minus class comprehension permit allowing every proper subclass of $V$ to be a set?

Tags: set-theory, lo.logic

Lets add a constant symbol $V$ to the signature of the language of set theory. So working in first order logic with equality, add the following axioms about $\in $ and $V$.

**Extensionality:** $\forall x \forall y (\forall z (z \in x \leftrightarrow z \in y) \to x=y)$

**Set construction (reflection):** if $\phi$ is a formula in which all and only symbols $y,x_1,..,x_n$ occur free, and non of them occur bound, in which the symbol $V$ doesn't occur, then: $$\forall x_1 \in V,...,\forall x_n \in V \\ \forall y (\phi \to y \in V) \to \exists x \in V \forall y (y \in x \leftrightarrow \phi)$$; is an axiom.

**Set-hood:** $\forall x \ (x \subsetneq V \leftrightarrow x \in V)$

Now this theory is formulated in the same langauge of [Ackermann's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ackermann_set_theory), it share with it the first two axioms and the right to left implication of the third axiom. However the left to right implication of the third axiom is in some sense daunting! The idea here is that this theory doesn't have comprehension axioms about proper classes, clearly by the third axiom all classes the second axiom constructs are sets! If we just add the class comprehension schema of Ackermann, then we immediately get a contradiction, since the Russell class would be a set. Now this theory easily prove all axioms of Zermelo set theory, and I'd think that (if consistent) it might even be equi-interpretable with the full Ackermann's set theory itself. Its also to be noted that if instead of adding the symbol $V$ as a constant, we added it as a one place predicate symbol (and so every formula $x \in V$ would be turned to $V(x)$) [as it is the case in the original formulation of Ackermann's where he actually used the symbol $\mathcal M$ for that], then it appears that Infinity would not be provable, which proves that the way how $V$ is added as a primitive does matter as regards the consistency strength of extensions of fragments of Ackermann's set theory.

> Question: What's the exact consistency strength of this theory?

Comment: Is $x \subsetneq V$ necessary instead of the simpler $x \subseteq V$?

Comment: Might a parameter-free version of comprehension be sufficient, [like it is for ZFC](http://www.math.uni-bonn.de/people/schlicht/ZFC_without_parameters.pdf)?

Comment: @user76284 if we allow $x \subseteq V$ then we'd have $V \in V$ therefore easily getting Russell's paradox by formula $x \in x_1  \land x \not \in x$ [just substitute$ x_1$ by $V$] and if you unleash parameters then you will encode $V$ in an indirect manner, so it would invoke Russell's paradox again. Yes parameter free would work but with the restriction of not containing $V$, of course. But I don't know its strength.

Comment: Doesn’t that mean your formula contains $V$ somewhere, though? Do you have an example for the indirect encoding?

Comment: Wait, why did you edit the construction schema?

Comment: @user76284, to have elements in $V$

Comment: But you can already prove $\varnothing \in V$ without that assumption.

Comment: @user76284 how?

Comment: I think like this: Consider $\phi y = \bot$. Then by the original schema $\exists x \forall y (y \in x \leftrightarrow \bot)$. That is, $\varnothing$ exists. Now it is trivially true that any element in $\varnothing$ belongs to $V$ (since there are no elements), so by the set-hood axiom $\varnothing \in V$.

Comment: @user76284 No to be an element of $V$ you need to be a *proper* subset of $V$, and there is no proof that the empty set is a *proper* subset of $V$. So you need to enforce that by modifying the set construction schema. Or simply add an axiom that $V$ is non empty.

Comment: Hmm, I see. That takes us back to the previous question of whether $x \subsetneq V$ is necessary.

Comment: @user76284, of course its necessary otherwise you'll have $V \in V$ and then you can substitute $V$ for any parameter $x_1$ and get the contradiction. As for an indirect way of coding $V$ if we unleash parameter (i.e. let the parameters range over all classes), then clearly the same would apply by substitution of parameters. The parameter free approach would work of course (provided that $V$ is shunned from being used) but its weak, I don't think it can prove pairing over all elements of $V$ unless you stipulate that all elements of $V$ are parameter free definable.

Comment: Sorry, how exactly are you getting the Russell contradiction from $V \in V$? Can you post a complete formal derivation? I think I might be misreading the axioms.

Comment: @user76284, OK, lets take  $\phi$ to be the formula $ y \in x_1 \land y \not \in y$, now let $x_1=V$, since you have $V \in V$ then this would fulfill the antecedent of set construction, and the rest of the proof is easy.

Comment: @user76284 you get $R \in R \leftrightarrow R \not \in R$.

Comment: Makes sense. I'll think about the parameter-free version.

Comment: @user76284, parameter free version is OK if you don't use the constant symbol $V$, but the problem is that it is very weak, how can you prove pairing within $V$ for example?

Comment: The schema of https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2499051/is-there-a-contradiction-hiding-in-this-alternative-set-theory-with-3-axioms has a different structure since the parameters for the antecedent and consequent are separate.

Comment: But in that case don't you need to show $\forall x_1 \forall x (x \not\in x \land x \in x_1 \rightarrow x \in V)$, even for those $x_1$ that are not $V$, before getting to the consequent?

Comment: Oh, I forgot it assumes all the parameters like $x_1$ are in $V$.

Comment: Since $x_1 \in V$ then by set-hood, this wold be proved.

Comment: Tricky. And making $V$ a predicate again would make us lose infinity.

Comment: @user76284 your structure would offer no protection, the same argument applies, actually if you take the formula $y \in x_1 \land y \not \in y$ you get the Russell set by letting $x_1=V$ in the consequent. You need to let $V$ be a predicate for that structure to work, and you lose infinity.

Comment: In that case, can we add the axiom of infinity I proposed to the predicate version you posted at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3251691/is-this-simple-class-theory-equi-interpretable-with-zfc? Or would it also be inconsistent?

Comment: @user76284, if you add a class of all constructible sets, then that class would act like $V$ here, so you need to amend 'set-hood' axiom as to require only *proper* subsets of $V$ to be constructible. And you need to change the parameter structure to the one given here (so the consequent of set construction scheme doesn't have unleashed parameters) since otherwise $V$ can seep through those unleashed parameters in the consequent. All in all you'll come back to this theory here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The theory is inconsistent.
Let ZG(x) be the formula ∀u∈x∀v∈u(v∈x)∧∀t(x∈t→∃s∈t(∀∈s(y∉t)))∧(∀t(∃s∈x(s∉t)→∃y∈x(y∉t∧∀u∈(x-t)(u∉y))))∧∀t∈x∃s∀v(v∈s↔(v=tνv=x))∧∀u∈x∃t∈x∀s(s∈t↔(s∈u∧∃r(r∈s)))∧∃t∀s(s∈t↔(s∈x∧∃r(r∈s)))
(That is x is transitive; if x is in t, then t has an ∈-minimal element; if x is not contained in t, then there is an ∈-minimal element of x which is not in t; if t is in x then
the pair {t,x} exists; if t is in x then t-{0} exists; and x-{0} exists.)

We note some simple properties of x for which ZG(x) holds:
      If x∈ then x⊆.(If x were not contained in V, then there is an ∈-minimal element m of x which is not in V. If m is not V, then by Set-hood m is in V. If m=V,then {V,x} exists
 and has no ∈-minimal element.)
      If x∈, then there is  a W∈ such that t is in W iff t is contained in x.(By the above property x⊆, and so anything contained in x is properly contained in V since x is not in
 x. Therefore by Set construction such a W must exist.) We will denote such a W by Px. 
      If x∈ then ZG(Px).

Suppose that ZG(x) implies x∈. By Set construction, there is a z∈ which consists of all x for which ZG(x) holds. Let y be the union of z. Then y is in  and ZG(y). Therefore ZG(Py).
Then Py is contained in y. But then y∈y which is impossible. Therefore there must be an x such that ZG(x) and x∉. If x is contained in  then x-{0} is in  and so x is in . If x is
not contained in  then there is an ∈-minimal element m of x which is not in . But then m-{0} is in  and so m is in .

Comment: Forgive me if I'm missing something, but doesn't $\phi y = \bot$ prove the empty set $\varnothing$ exists, and then $\varnothing \in V$, and then $\phi y = \forall x (x \in y \leftrightarrow x = \varnothing)$ shows the unit set $\{\varnothing\}$ exists and is also in $V$?

Comment: @ZuhairAl-Johar I don't understand - user76284's comment seems correct to me.

Comment: @NoahSchweber, you came late. Kirmayer is responding to my old presentation of the theory in which I missed stipulating the asserted class in set construction to be a set. the user 76284 comment in that old formulation fails because the empty class need not be a proper subclass of $V$.

Comment: @ I think you are right! I think this proof can be simplified to require any object x to fulfill ZG if and only if  x-{0} exists and whatever class t that x is not a subset of then x has a minimal element m that is not in t and for which m-{0} exists. This would enforce every ZG object to be a member of V. Clearly every von Neumann ordinal in V fulfills ZG, then the property "ZG(x) and x is a von Neumann ordinal" would enact Burali-Forti. Great! Thanks!

Comment: I wonder if the theory presented at the below mentioned link would be subject to the same argument of inconsistency? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3251691/is-this-simple-class-theory-equi-interpretable-with-zfc